# How to ensure that part of code (which contains async) would be called only once?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7, thread-safety

So, I have a method, which contains async call to the server.
That code is called from 3rd party tool, which somehow sometimes calls same method several times in a row from different threads, so I can't affect that.

What I want to be sure is that my method is called once, and then, another calls should be ignored.

At first, I tried to lock(locker) with bool isBusy, but that is not satisfied me, as async request was still called several times from second thread, which was fast enough to see isBusy=true;

Then, I tried Monitor

```
                object obj = new object();
                Monitor.TryEnter(obj);
                try
                {

                    var res = await _dataService.RequestServerAsync(SelectedIndex, e.StartIndex, e.Count);

                    ****
                }
                finally 
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(obj);
                }
```

However, on `Exit()`, I'm getting exception:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException'

Is there any other way to guarantee only 1 time execution of the code?

Comment: What 3rd party tool are you using?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put in the class:

```
private int entered = 0;
```

and in the method:

```
if (Interlocked.Increment(ref entered) != 1)
{
    return;
}
```

Only the first call to the method will be able to change `entered` from 0 to 1. The others will make it 2, 3, 4, 5...

Clearly you'll need something to reset the `entered` if you want your method to be refireable...

```
Interlocked.Exchange(ref entered, 0);
```

at the end of a successful call to the method.

Ah... and it isn't possible to use `lock`/`Monitor.*` around an `await`, because the current thread of the method can change, while nearly all the synchronization libraries expect that the thread you use to enter a lock is the same you use to exit the lock.

You can even use the `Interlocked.CompareExchange()`...

```
if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref entered, 1, 0) != 0)
{
    return;
}
```

The first thread to enter will be able to exchange the value of entered from 0 to 1, and it will receive the old value, 0 (so failing the if and continuing in the remaining code). The other threads will fail the `CompareExchange` and see the "current" value of 1, so entering the if and exiting the method

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Can i also use Exchange() instead of Increment()? I would be needed to store some info about current page, so its looking like a nice place to store that info.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko No, you would need to use `if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref entered, 1, 0) != 0) return;`. The first one to enter is able to change from 0 to 1 and receives the old value (0). The others fail the change and receive the current value (1).

Comment: Hm.. anyway, thanks for answer - now i know, where to jump into for additional info.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko Technically the `CompareExchange` is safer, because after 4 billion calls the `Interlocked.Increment` will return to 0 and have a success.

Answer (score 4):

If you do want to restrict multiple threads using the same method concurrently then I would use the `Semaphore` class to facilitate the required thread limit; here's how...

A semaphore is like a mean night club bouncer, it has been provide a club capacity and is not allowed to exceed this limit. Once the club is full, no one else can enter... A queue builds up outside. Then as one person leaves another can enter (analogy thanks to J. Albahari).

A `Semaphore` with a value of one is equivalent to a `Mutex` or `Lock` except that the `Semaphore` has no owner so that it is thread ignorant. Any thread can call `Release` on a `Semaphore` whereas with a `Mutex`/`Lock` only the thread that obtained the `Mutex`/`Lock` can release it.

Now, for your case we are able to use `Semaphore`s to limit concurrency and prevent too many threads from executing a particular piece of code at once. In the following example five threads try to enter a night club that only allows entry to three...

```
class BadAssClub
{
    static SemaphoreSlim sem = new SemaphoreSlim(3);
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
            new Thread(Enter).Start(i);
    }

    // Enfore only three threads running this method at once.
    static void Enter(int i)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i + " wants to enter.");
            sem.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine(i + " is in!");
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * (int)i);
            Console.WriteLine(i + " is leaving...");
        }
        finally
        {
            sem.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that `SemaphoreSlim` is a lighter weight version of the `Semaphore` class and incurs about a quarter of the overhead. it is sufficient for what you require.

I hope this helps.

Comment: There is no reason why they cannot be used inside an `async` method.